# httpd.service Cannot connect to database Centos 7

Tags: django, centos7, wsgi, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL Unix domain socket from a python web application with mod_wsgi. Relevant system components:

- CentOS 7 x64
- Python 2.7.5
- **SELinux disabled**

PostgreSQL is listening on standard port 5432 and I have no problems to use it via TCP/IP at 127.0.0.1:5432, but when I try to connect to its Unix domain socket, I have a following error:

```
Cannot connect to database:  could not connect to server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?*
```

File `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` exists and I can connect using `psql`.

However, when I stop apache with systemctl stop httpd.service and restart it again with `/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND`, everything works fine, including the pages that do require database access

With SELinux disabled, I do not understand why there is problems when httpd start with `systemctl start httpd.service`.

EDIT:

I've changed `unix_socket_directories = '/tmp,/var/pgsql_sock'` in  /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf. I also changed config in `setting.py` in my django app `HOST='/var/pgsql_sock'`. Now it works fine with httpd.service.

Comment: It's a `unix_socket_directories` mismatch between the default compiled into the `libpq` on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `/etc/ld.so.conf` and the default in the PostgreSQL server you're running. `SHOW unix_socket_directories;` in PostgreSQL will likely output a different path.

Comment: unix_socket_directories= /tmp

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `/tmp` to store sockets for interprocess communication in this scenario, because Apache uses [*private* /tmp directories](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/), a security feature that ensures that a process can only see its own /tmp directory; it cannot see what other processes write into /tmp because those other processes are actually writing into different directories.

This means that Apache cannot see the PostgreSQL socket.

You will need to continue using a local TCP connection.

You should also *not* disable SELinux, and [use the correct boolean to allow the web server to talk to the database](https://serverfault.com/a/679132/126632).

Comment: why starting apache  with /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND the problem disappear? @MichaelHampton

Comment: @xav Presumably because it doesn't `chroot(...)` into a private filesystem namespace if you do that.

Comment: @xav because the private /tmp directory is a systemd option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm mostly a fan of using local TCP connections as Michael Hampton pointed out, however you *can* manually specify another directory and / or symbolically link to another location that'll work around this issue.

For example:

```
mkdir /var/pgsql_socket/ 
ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

And point Apache at /var/pgsql_socket

Answer (score 1):

Solved by editing /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf

```
unix_socket_directories = '/tmp/var/pgsql_sock'
```

Then issued:

```
mkdir /var/pgsql_sock/

chown postgres:postgres  /var/pgsql_sock
```

edited setting.py in my django app `.....HOST='/var/pgsql_sock'`

Now it works fine with httpd.service